# SQL Update column and ignore duplicate key errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to update a column with concatanated values from other columns in the same row. The column I am updating is unique, and do the the nature of this I will sometimes end up with duplicate key errors. I am looking to ignore these errors and simply update one of the records and ignore the other ones.

My query looks something like this:

```
update [Table] set Coolname = lower(Fname) + lower(Lname)
where Coolname like '%s' 
and staticID=1995
and Fname is not null 
and Lname is not null
```

Now in the cases where Fname and Lname match in two rows, I would like for only the first records Coolname to be updated.

Thanks. (MS SQL Server)

Comment: Ignoring a duplicate key error is not really a good practice... If it doesnt matter that a value exists once or multiple times, fine, but don't declare it as a primary_key or unique...

Comment: Understood, this is a rather unique case and is required however.

Comment: How do you define "first records"?   Is there a key of some kind?   Remember, by itself, a table has no concept of first or last

Comment: Understood Sparky....first is of no matter, I should have written 'one of' instead. As long as only one of the records is updated then we are fine

Comment: Why do you need a "Coolname" column if it is just the product of Fname and Lname? This could be handled with a view. Just define the column as SELECT LOWER(Fname) + LOWER(Lname) AS Coolname.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
UPDATE[Table] 
SET Coolname = lower(Fname) + lower(Lname)
WHERE 'PRIMARY_KEY' IN 
    (SELECT top 1 'PRIMARY_KEY' FROM [Table] 
        WHERE Coolname LIKE'%s' 
        AND staticID=1995
        AND Fname IS NOT NULL 
        AND Lname IS NOT NULL );
```

Don't have experience in SQL-Server so query should only be a hint... Hope I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a couple of CTEs:

```
;With CoolNames as (
    select *,lower(Fname) + lower(Lname) as NewCoolName from Table
    where Coolname like '%s' 
    and staticID=1995
    and Fname is not null 
    and Lname is not null
), Ordered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NewCoolName ORDER BY staticID) as rn
    from Coolnames cn
)
UPDATE Ordered SET CoolName = NewCoolName where rn = 1
```

Where, since you don't care about which one gets selected for the update, I've chosen to `ORDER BY staticID` - which I happen to know is the same for all rows, so this really is going to let the server arbitrarily select one to update.

If the collisions are happening, not as you've alluded to in your question between two rows eligible for update, but instead between one row that's eligible to be updated and an *existing* row where `CoolName` is already set, then add

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * from Table t where t.CoolName = cn.CoolName)
```

into the `Ordered` CTE.